# Yacc program not recognizing function declaration

Tags: compiler-construction, function, grammar, yacc, context-free-grammar

I think my program should be able to recognize the following as a function declaration:

```
int fn(int i) { int n; return; }
```

but it doesn't.

Here's the relevant part of my yacc file:

```
program : declaration_list ; 

declaration_list : declaration_list declaration | declaration ;

declaration : var_declaration 
            | fun_declaration 
            | '$' { printTable();};

var_declaration : type_specifier ID ';' {$2->value = 0; $2->arraysize = 0;};
                | type_specifier ID '[' NUM ']' ';' {$2->arraysize = $4;printf("Array size is %d", $2->arraysize);} ;

type_specifier : INT | VOID ;

fun_declaration : type_specifier ID '(' params ')' compound_stmt {printf("function declaration\n"); printf("Parameters: \n", $2->args); } ;


params : param_list | VOID ;

param_list : param_list ',' param
           | param ;

param : type_specifier ID | type_specifier ID '[' ']' ;

compound_stmt : '{' local_declarations statement_list '}' {printf("exiting scope\n"); } ;

local_declarations : local_declarations var_declaration
                   | /* empty */ ;

statement_list : statement_list statement
               | /* empty */ ;

statement : expression_stmt
          | compound_stmt
          | selection_stmt
          | iteration_stmt
          | return_stmt ;

expression_stmt : expression ';'
                | ';' ;

selection_stmt : IF '(' expression ')' statement
               | IF '(' expression ')' statement ELSE statement ;

iteration_stmt : WHILE '(' expression ')' statement ;

return_stmt : RETURN ';' | RETURN expression ';' ;
```

Why does it not recognize it?

Comment: What is the output? Where does it produce the error?

Comment: If I type int main(void) { int it will say "yyerror: syntax error" after I type int.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer to your question but a suggestion for debugging.

After each of the rules, add a `printf` statement which tells you that the rule has been matched. Take a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763243/bison-shift-instead-of-reduce-with-reduce-reduce-errors/1775963#1775963) for hints. Then run your input through the grammar and see what it is doing.

Another hint, for asking questions, is to try to reduce your problem to the simplest case which reproduces the error. In the case of the above grammar, strip out all of the rules which you don't expect to match this particular example before posting it. Also, post a complete program, with the `%token` declarations, so people can compile it and try it out for themselves. Even better is to post the lexer too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like:

```
declaration : type_specifier ID ';' {$2->value = 0; $2->arraysize = 0;};
            | type_specifier ID '[' NUM ']' ';' {$2->arraysize = $4;printf("Array size is %d", $2->arraysize);} ;
            | type_specifier ID '(' params ')' compound_stmt {printf("function declaration\n"); printf("Parameters: \n", $2->args); } ;

            | '$' { printTable();};
```

type_specifier : INT | VOID ;

Answer (score -1):

Just looked at the line where you have

```
local_declarations : local_declarations var_declaration
                   | /* empty */ ;
```

That line looks troublesome to me, since you have it like a recursive statement...

Hope this gives you the hint,
Best regards,
Tom.